# How to select one row from multiple rows of strings and store the values separated by commars

Tags: java

I have a csv file thats converted each row into strings and i want a user to select a numbe 1- 5 and it would store what row the user entered.
The string that has been made from the csv file is below.

1,Mazda CX-9,7,Automatic ,Premium,150

2,VW Golf,5,Automatic ,Standard,59

3,Toyota Corolla,5,Automatic ,Premium,55

4,VW Tiguan,7,Automatic ,Premium,110

5,Ford Falcon,5,Manual,Standard,60

```
public static void carSelection() throws IOException{
    String CSVFileName = "CarList.csv";
    File file = new File(CSVFileName);
            System.out.println("To make a booking:");
    System.out.println("     Select the car number from the car list");
    try {
        //reads file
     Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
     //while the file has lines to read
    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        //  read the line to a string
    String line = scanner.nextLine();
}
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

Comment: I'd be tempted to make use of [OpenCSV](https://www.baeldung.com/opencsv), but failing that, I'd read the file contents into a `List` of some kind and then just cherry pick the row the user selected

Comment: Or failing that, with the code you already have `if (line.startsWith(userSelection + ",")) { //store it }`

Comment: At this line String line = scanner.nextLine(); you can actually save the CSV to the collection and then ask for the user selection and fetch and store the user selection.

For ex - if the user selection is based on the index use the array/ArrayList else make use of the Map of cars and description.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear. But following code will ask user for a number and print the correspondig csv line.

```
 public static void carSelection() throws IOException {
    
    String CSVFileName = "CarList.csv";
    System.out.println("To make a booking:");
    System.out.println("Select the car number from the car list");
    // Enter data using BufferReader
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(Paths.get(CSVFileName));
    int inputNr = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
    String line = lines.skip(inputNr - 1).findFirst().get();
    System.out.println(line);        
}
```